# PHP Yii2 extension development

Tags: php, yii2

Could you please advise on the following question: how to properly set up a development and debugging environment for a PHP Yii2 extension module?

If working within the 'vendor' directory, it's typically included in the .gitignore file. However, when moving extension files to the project directory, the namespace doesn't load properly and raises errors.

```
Failed to instantiate component or class "comp\blog\Module"
```

подскажите пожалуйста вопрос
как правильно настроить рабочую среду для разработки и отладки модуля-расширения для PHP Yii2
если работать в папке vendor она же в .gitignore
а если переносиш файлы расширения в папку проекта то namespace не загружает пишет

```
Failed to instantiate component or class "comp\blog\Module"
```

If working within the 'vendor' directory, it's typically included in the .gitignore file. However, when moving extension files to the project directory, the namespace doesn't load properly and raises errors.

Comment: [English is required for all content on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions)

Comment: And please provide a [mre] of the issue to make it easier for people to help you. See also [ask]. As you're new please take the [tour] as well. You can [edit] your post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way I'm doing it: I create a directory `dev/myExtension` in the `@app` directory. There I put a `composer.json` file with the following content:

```
{
    "name": "schmauch/my-extension",
    "type": "yii2-extension",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "schmauch\\myExtension\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Then I add my extension to the `require` part and the according path in the `repsotories` part in the app's `composer.json` file:

```
...
    "require": {
        ...
        "schmauch/my-extension": ""
    },
    ....
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "/path/to/your/app/dev/myExtension"
        }
        ...
    ]
```

Now I can install the extension with `composer update`. In fact composer links the `dev/myExtension` directory to `@app/vendor/schmauch/myExtension` and adds the autoloader namespace...